# How to get text from word file using php accurately?

Tags: php

I am using  doc2txt.class.php  class to get the txt from word file using php and I am using the below code

```
require("doc2txt.class.php");
$docObj = new Doc2Txt("test.docx");
$txt = $docObj->convertToText();
```

My word file contains the below text

```
MWONGOZO WA MAOMBI MAALUMU (MAOMBI YA HATARI).
Huu ni Mfano Tu, Jinsi Ya Kuomba Na Maeneo Ya Kuombea! Unatakiwa pamoja na KUWA NA BIDII, KUMTEGEMEA SANA ROHO MTAKATIFU NI MUHIMU SANA!
MAOMBI MAALUMU YA JINSI YA KUPAMBANA KATIKA VITA VYA KIROHO
Jinsi Ya Kuomba Maombi Haya
```

But output I get is little different my output is

```
MWONGOZO WA MAOMBI MAALUMU (MAOMBI YA HATARI).Huu ni Mfano Tu, Jinsi Ya Kuomba Na Maeneo Ya Kuombea! Unatakiwa pamoja na KUWA NA BIDII, KUMTEGEMEA SANA ROHO MTAKATIFU NI MUHIMU SANA! MAOMBI MAALUMU YA JINSI YA KUPAMBANA KATIKA VITA VYA KIROHOJinsi Ya Kuomba Maombi Haya
```

as you can see output contains this word KIROHO Jinsi as one word KIROHOJinsi
so when I count the number of words it gives 45 words but actually there
are 46 words.

Is there any way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Looks like you are loosing the line breaks and therefore 2 words are being run together. Maybe https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord

Comment: No I am using PHPWord libaray,I am using doc2txt.class.php.

Comment: Exactly! I was suggesting you look at that instead

Comment: okay,but what is the issue with the above code?how can I resolve?

Comment: You need only count from document?

Comment: Yes,I want to count words.

Comment: add break or space at end of first line and second line and so on. $array =  nl2br($myfile); then after explode so it will convert into array then use count for that array.

Comment: I have done for txt file.

Comment: can you show me the code? because for word file it does not work?

Comment: I have posted my code. If it will helpful then thumb up for my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked this code for txt file and it is working fine. I think this might help you. Thanks

```
$myfile = file_get_contents("test.txt");

    $array = explode("\n", $myfile);

    $count = null;
    if (!empty($array))
    {
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($array as $rowarray)
        {

            $a1 = array_filter(explode(" ", trim($rowarray)));
            $count = $count + count($a1);
        }
        echo $count;
    }
```